# elasticsearch-cloud-aws plugin not working with IAM role

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to set up an elasticsearch cluster on aws ec2 machines using elasticsearch-cloud-aws plugin. I followed instructions from the github readme file but wasn't able to make it work with IAM role set up.

I am using ES 1.7.1 and plugin version 2.7.0

Started EC2 instances with IAM role associated with the following policies:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1439999260000",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DescribeAvailabilityZones",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:DescribeRegions",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

In the elasticsearch configuration files on all the instances a modified following settings:

```
cluster.name: my_cluster
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.type: ec2
discovery.type: ec2
discovery.ec2.groups: my_security_group
discovery.ec2.availability_zones: eu-west-1b
```

With the DEBUG level for discovery module following is found in the es log.

```
[2015-08-19 18:41:12,024][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [Misfit] using ping.timeout [3s], join.timeout [1m], master_election.filter_client [true], master_election.filter_data [false]
[2015-08-19 18:41:12,025][DEBUG][discovery.zen.fd         ] [Misfit] [master] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3]
[2015-08-19 18:41:12,027][DEBUG][discovery.zen.fd         ] [Misfit] [node  ] uses ping_interval [1s], ping_timeout [30s], ping_retries [3]
[2015-08-19 18:41:12,785][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [Misfit] using host_type [PRIVATE_IP], tags [{}], groups [[ES-development-expose]] with any_group [true], availability_zones [[eu-west-1b]]
[2015-08-19 18:41:13,479][INFO ][node                     ] [Misfit] initialized
[2015-08-19 18:41:13,479][INFO ][node                     ] [Misfit] starting ...
[2015-08-19 18:41:13,560][INFO ][transport                ] [Misfit] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.29:9300]}
[2015-08-19 18:41:13,581][INFO ][discovery                ] [Misfit] es-aws-dev/W24WvY0yQyew0khFFDrQVA
[2015-08-19 18:41:14,805][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [Misfit] using dynamic discovery nodes []
[2015-08-19 18:41:16,433][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [Misfit] using dynamic discovery nodes []
[2015-08-19 18:41:18,064][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [Misfit] using dynamic discovery nodes []
[2015-08-19 18:41:18,067][DEBUG][discovery.ec2            ] [Misfit] filtered ping responses: (filter_client[true], filter_data[false]) {none}
[2015-08-19 18:41:18,074][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Misfit] new_master [Misfit][W24WvY0yQyew0khFFDrQVA][ip-10-0-0-29.eu-west-1.compute.internal][inet[/10.0.0.29:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-08-19 18:41:18,101][INFO ][http                     ] [Misfit] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.29:9200]}
[2015-08-19 18:41:18,101][INFO ][node                     ] [Misfit] started
[2015-08-19 18:41:18,102][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Misfit] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Cluster is not formed,rather two separate masters.

I have verified that IAM role on machine works. But is it possible to verify what entries were returned to ec2 node?
Any hint what I've overlooked?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I set aws region as well via cloud.aws.region it started to operate as expected.